# If statement to change Div id

Tags: php, html, css

I'm writing some php/html code. I have a css file that has several backgrounds.  Is there any way to write an if statement to select a div id depending on a php variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could do it in-line in your html/php

```
<div id="<?= ($true_or_false) ? 'div_id_1' : 'div_id_2' ?>">div content</div>
```

Or... if you have more than 2 div id options just do an classic if statement

```
<?php

if($condition) {
    $div_id = 'something';
}
else if ($another_condition) {
    $div_id = 'something_else';
}
..etc

?>

<div id="<?php echo $div_id ?>">div content</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can generate CSS via PHP, first sort everything out and then print with text/css header.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/css");
?>
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

Anyway you need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
<?php
    $divId = $someBoolean ? "peaches" : "pineapples";
?>
<div id="<?php echo $divId ?>">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// file: style.php
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/css");
?>

#mydiv {
  background: url('<?php

switch($_GET['background'])
  {
  case 1:
    echo 'blah1.jpg';
  //etc...
  }

?>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways you can do this. You can do it in php and assign a different class or id. Or you do it with javascript and change the class or id after the page loads.